# How to use variable length parameter list with only one reference parameter?

Tags: c++

Recently I meet an annoying problem that I want to define functions like this:

```
std::string my_sprintf(const char* format, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    ...
}
std::string my_sprintf(const std::string& format, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format); // error
    ...
}
```

But it seems reference value can't be the last parameter when using variable length parameter list.

Is that a way that I can let user use std::string as format string?

Maybe factors or something else that detect std::string and convert it as c_str() would work, but I don't know how to deal with the following variable length parameter list.

Edit:
  I'm not using variadic template because i'm using vsprintf inside. Maybe avoid using vsprintf and using std::stringstream is an option?

Comment: [tag:c] is not [tag:c++].

Comment: C++ way to make `printf` is to use variadic templates [like here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17671772/c11-variadic-printf-performance)

Comment: Why not use variadic template instead ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The behaviour is *undefined*: See C++ Standard 18.10/3 (for C++11 and C++14), or [cppreference.com: Variadic Arguments](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments).

Essentially you can only use types that are available in C with `va_start`, although an exception is made for the `std::nullptr_t` type.

Comment: They are also called **POD** *Plain Old Data*, [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c).

Comment: I know excatly that this is forbidden, but I'm just asking is there a way to do so.

Comment: Not with `va_start`, no. But there's no reason why you couldn't use variadic *templates*. Or just deep copy the string. The i/o stage of your function will be the bottleneck, not the deep copy.

Comment: @Bathsheba Because i'm using vsprintf inside, it there a better way to avoid using it?

Comment: You should indicate which C++ standard you are referring to: in the C++14 standard the information about `va_start()` is in 18.10/3 .

Answer (score 2):

In C++, the way to pass *"unknown"* arguments is to use variadic template:

```
template <typename ... Ts>
std::string my_sprintf(const std::string& format, Ts&&...args)
{
    return my_sprintf(format.c_str(), std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
}
```

and you version with `const char*` should probably also be variadic template, by using `sprintf` instead of `vsprintf`.

Comment: @user2079303: With both version variadic, it works [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/649e95afbeee69b4). But indeed, with ellipsis, it is ambiguous and requires some renaming to workaround that.

Comment: @Jarod42 oh, right. I tried to understand this code in a vacuum - without realizing that there is an overload. Sorry about the noise.