# Preparing C++ Json Request

Tags: c++, json, string, c++14

I am trying to prepare json request using c++. Like this:

```
string key = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

std::string data = "{\n"
"    \"foo\": key\n"
"}";
```

When I print this, it's shows like :

```
"foo": key
```

But I need like this :

```
"foo": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
```

So, please someone help me. How to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: To begin with, and to help you solve your problem, the C++ compiler will not parse the contents of string literals, looking for variables or other expressions. Fortunately you can append to `std::string` objects using the normal `+` operator. Like e.g. `std::string a = "a", b = "b", ab = a + b;`

Comment: To continue, you really shouldn't attempt to create or parse JSON yourself, it's really quite complicated. Find a library to help you with it, there are quite a few C++ and C libraries that you can use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37956090/string-interpolation-in-c-construct-a-stdstring-with-embedded-values-e-g

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ doesn't expand variables inside a string constant, so if you have "key" inside such a string, it'll just be interpreted as the string "key" rather than expanded as a variable.

What you want to do is concatenate the contents of the variable "key" with the rest of your string.  In C++, you can just do this with the concatenation operator "+".

So you'll want something like:

```
std::string data = "{\n"
"    \"foo\": " + key + "\n"
"}"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not expect the string `key` to be replaced with value of variable `key`. Though some languages support string interpolation but as far as I know `c++` does not. You can create the json string by concatenating the string before `key`, the `key`, and string after `key`

```cpp
std::string data = "{\n \"foo\": " + key + "\n}";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  std::string key = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
  std::string data = "{\n"
  "    \"foo\": ";
  data += key;
  data += "\n"
  "}";
```

Answer (score 1):

you can for sure do what others suggested:

```
std::string data = "{\n\"foo\":" + key + "\n}";
```

but you can use (and i would advice you) a nice lib called nlohmann::json

and do:

```
nlohmann::json j;
std::string k{"123-ABC"};
j["foo"] = k;
std::cout << j.dump();
//prints {"foo":"123-ABC"}
std::cout << j.dump(2);
//prints:
//    {
//      "foo": "123-ABC"
//    }
```