# C++ inline string interpolation

Tags: c++, string, formatting, string-interpolation

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37956090/string-interpolation-in-c-construct-a-stdstring-with-embedded-values-e-g#37956090), which is nice, but not enough for me.

They offer

```
boost::format("error! value was %1% but I expected %2%") % actualValue % expectedValue
```

Which is nice, but much less readable than what I would like (in some syntax):

```
boost::format("error! value was %actualValue % but I expected %expectedValue%")
```

In C# that is

```
$"error! value was {actualValue} but I expected {expectedValue}"
```

In Python that is

```
f"error! value was {actualValue} but I expected {expectedValue}"
```

**Is that supported somehow in C++?**

Comment: Short answer: No.

Comment: Note that the C++20 standard adds [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format). It still doesn't "fix" your wanted syntax though, which depends on the compiler not really doing any kind of parsing of string literals (besides handling escape sequences).

Comment: You could use the stream syntax if you find it closer to what you want to achieve.

Comment: You could consider offering a bounty on the linked question instead of reposting.

Comment: Not sure how close this is to what you want, but what you could do is to store your values in a map and then have your own replacement routines. Like `map<string, string> variables; variables["actualValue"] = 1; cout << replace_variables("The actual value is $actualValue$", variables);`, with the function containing a loop over the map and appropriate replacement calls.

Answer (score 0):

There is a C++ standard proposal. [Interpolated literals](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1819r0.html)

The samples.

```
int port = 27015;
std::cout << f"Connecting on port {port}...\n";
int get_result() { return 42; }
std::cout << f"The result is {get_result()}\n";
```

I like this kind of syntax. It's concise and beautiful.

Unfortunately, there is no real C++ implementation libraries until 2022.8.

Comment: I wrote the proposal, and I am not associated with Microsoft. There is also no implementation of this proposal whatsoever yet.

Comment: I'm Sorry, Vittorio, I misunderstood something with your email address in the proposal. The answer has been revised. By the way, I'm learning C++ now, and I know C++ has many advanced weapons. Can we implement it by current C++'s weapons? or does it need some compiler's support to achieve it? I use f-string in python, it supplys efficiency. I'm looking forward to this efficiency in C++, too. Thanks for your proposal, Vittorio. :)