# Defining a set of pre-populated protobuf messages?

Tags: protocol-buffers

I want to be able to supply a pre-instantiated message by name rather than populating it from scratch. For example, given the following schema:

```
message Animal {
  required int32 num_legs = 1;
  required int32 num_eyes = 2;
}

message Zoo {
  repeated Animal animals;
}
```

I want to be able quickly to define a Zoo in my config file by choosing from a set of known animals:

```
// config.json
zoo: {
  animals: [snake, bird]
}
```

where snake and bird are already defined:

```
// animals.json
bird: {
  num_legs: 2
  num_eyes: 2
}

snake: {
  num_legs: 0
  num_eyes: 2
}
```

What's the most elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The protobuf API has methods to convert protobuf⬌JSON.  For C++ you can use [`util::JsonStringToMessage`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.util.json_util#JsonStringToMessage.details), other languages have their API versions too (you didn't specify a language).  Wrap this in a simple helper function and use your language's multi-line string constant syntax to embed the message in JSON format directly into your source.

To get your named predefined messages, use a language that has string interpolation.  (Not native to C++, unfortunately, but [here is a SO answer talking about ways you might do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37956091/751579).)