# How does QMessageLogger magic work?

Tags: c++, qt, logging

I am working on a logger framework for QT applications. I am not using `QMessageLogger` directly because of understanding and learning purposes. There is one thing about one `QMessageLogger` functionality that I would really like to have in my logger but I dont know how does it work. Lets take for example the `qDebug` macro:

```
#define qDebug QMessageLogger(QT_MESSAGELOG_FILE, QT_MESSAGELOG_LINE, QT_MESSAGELOG_FUNC).debug
```

One can call this function in 2 ways:
1st way:

```
qDebug("abc = %u", abc);
```

2nd way:

```
qDebug() << "abc = " << abc;
```

I am looking at the library code, but I cannot quite understand how is it implemented that one can work with `QMessageLogger` by using `va_args` as well as some stream object.
How can I achieve such effect? I would really appreciate all help, would be grateful for an example.

Here is my `print` method body. I need to achieve simmilar functionality with the "stream" way:

```
/*!
 * \brief Adds the log line to the print queue.
 * \param lvl: Log level of the line.
 * \param text: Formatted input for va_list.
 */
void CBcLogger::print(MLL::ELogLevel lvl, const char* text, ...)
{
    // check if logger initialized
    if (!m_loggerStarted)
        return;

    // check if log level sufficient
    if (lvl > m_setLogLvl)
        return;

    logLine_t logline;
    logline.loglvl = lvl;
    logline.datetime = QDateTime::currentDateTime();

    va_list argptr;
    va_start(argptr, text);

    char* output = NULL;
    if (vasprintf(&output, text, argptr))
    {
        logline.logstr = output;
        delete output;
    }

    va_end(argptr);
    emit addNewLogLine(logline);
}
```

Comment: Side note: if you write C++11 and use C's variadic arguments, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: How should i do it properly?

Comment: Don't use variadic arguments. Forget that they exist. See e.g. [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25392245/1329652).

Comment: Ive seen the thread, i understand its an alternative but whats wrong with printf really?

Comment: It's not type safe, and is unnecessary in C++11. You might as well ask "what's wrong with C".

Comment: I get the point. Is this the case exacly? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn913181.aspx

Comment: The article you link to explores this issue, yes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you need to understand what is the following

```
QMessageLogger(QT_MESSAGELOG_FILE, QT_MESSAGELOG_LINE, QT_MESSAGELOG_FUNC).debug
```

The above line constructs a `QMessageLogger` instance and immediately accesses its debug member. Since it is a macro, it's also important what you write in code right after it.

If you look at what `QMessageLogger::debug` is, you'll see four overloads, and the first two of them are pertinent to your question:

```
void debug(const char *msg, ...) const Q_ATTRIBUTE_FORMAT_PRINTF(2, 3);
QDebug debug() const;
QDebug debug(const QLoggingCategory &cat) const;
QDebug debug(CategoryFunction catFunc) const;
```

Now the matter should be simple. If you call `qDebug("abc = %u", abc)`, you're calling the first overload, and the expanded macro is as follows:

```
QMessageLogger(QT_MESSAGELOG_FILE, QT_MESSAGELOG_LINE, QT_MESSAGELOG_FUNC).debug("abc = %u", abc)
```

which is more or less equal to

```
QMessageLogger temp(QT_MESSAGELOG_FILE, QT_MESSAGELOG_LINE, QT_MESSAGELOG_FUNC);
temp.debug("abc = %u", abc);
```

In the second case you're calling an overload that returns a [`QDebug`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdebug.html) object. `QDebug` has overloaded [`operator<<`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdebug.html#operator-lt-lt). The expanded macro is as follows:

```
QMessageLogger(QT_MESSAGELOG_FILE, QT_MESSAGELOG_LINE, QT_MESSAGELOG_FUNC).debug() << "abc = " << abc;
```

which is more or less equal to

```
QMessageLogger temp(QT_MESSAGELOG_FILE, QT_MESSAGELOG_LINE, QT_MESSAGELOG_FUNC);
QDebug anotherTemp = temp.debug();
anotherTemp << "abc = " << abc;
```

---

Here's a simple implementation of such logger:

```
void addNewLogLine(char const* ptr){
    cout << "addNewLogLine: " << ptr << endl;
}
struct LoggerHelper
{
    std::stringstream s;

    explicit LoggerHelper()=default;
    LoggerHelper(LoggerHelper&&) = default;

    ~LoggerHelper(){
        auto str = s.str();
        addNewLogLine(str.c_str());
    }

    template<typename T>
    LoggerHelper& operator<<(T const& val){
        s << val;
        return *this;
    }
};

struct Logger
{
    void operator()(char const* fmt, ...) const {
        char* buf;
        va_list args;
        va_start(args, fmt);
        vasprintf(&buf, fmt, args);
        va_end(args);
        addNewLogLine(buf);
        free(buf);
    }

    LoggerHelper operator()() const {
        return LoggerHelper{};
    }
};
```

[demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/2jPOlI9nodvun99d)

Several notes:

- I adhered to your interface, but personally, I'd use variadic templates instead of va_args
- you're supposed to `free` the buffer returned by `vasprintf`. `free` is not interchangeable with `delete` or `delete[]`
- I used `std::stringstream`, but changing it to `QTextStream` or any other should be simple enough
- You don't need to implement helper as a separate class if you're okay with allowing `log << "foo" << "bar"` syntax as opposed to `log() << "foo" << "bar"`

Comment: So if my standard method is: `void print(MLL::ELogLevel lvl, const char* text, ...);`, should I add an overload, looking maybe like this: `QTextStream print(MLL::ELogLevel lvl) const;` ?

Comment: @ŁukaszPrzeniosło I kinda missed the second part of the question. I'll update it. You can do what you did, but tbh I'd just overload `operator()` in my logger, as well as `operator<<`

Comment: I would appreciate it. Because for now I am not sure how to do it the way I showed, because in the pint function I check if logger is initialised and if not i return. But here I have to return a `QTextStream` so I cant return ie. 0.

Comment: I have added my current `print` method to the question.

Comment: @ŁukaszPrzeniosło added an example, pointed out a bug in your code ;)

Comment: I didnt know about the free vs delete problem, thank you. I will try to implement your example. Thank you a lot.

Comment: @ŁukaszPrzeniosło let me know if you have problems :)

Comment: I did run a a slight problem... The general concept you introduced works, but I am having problems implementing it into my current system. Here are my classes declarations and an example main file: https://pastebin.com/R3vYkwX4 . At line 85 compiller will call an error, because the struct `LoggerHelper` is not known yet. Also for some reason he doesnt allow me to do forward declaration. This is the last thing I need to do. I would appreciate help.

Comment: @ŁukaszPrzeniosło http://pastebin.com/HV8hP2J4 line 73 fwd declaration, 87 changed op() to just declaration inside the class, 130 defined op()

Comment: Damn you are fast... :I will check this 1st thing in the morning because I had to close the pc now. Thank you!

Comment: I cannot figure out how to call the created operator through the instance. It should be something like this I believe `CBcLogger::instance()(MLL::ELogLevel::LInfo) << "test 2";` but I cannot get it to compile.

Comment: Ok, I think I managed to do this. I added an override print function that looks like this: `LoggerHelper CBcLogger::print(MLL::ELogLevel lvl) const { return LoggerHelper(lvl); }`. I am not sure this is the right way and I am sure I dont understand this fully yet, but I am happy it works. Thank you very much @krzaq