# How does fprintf format arguments?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am currently trying to pass an arbitrary number of parameters of `MyType` to `fprintf` like this:

```
void myPrint(const char* fmt, std::initializer_list<MyType> args)
{
  fprintf(stdout, fmt, args);
}
```

where `MyType` is basically a variant and can be constructed from most common types (int, string, uint*, bool, ...). Now when calling `myPrint(...)` like this

```
myPrint("I am a hex int: %x", { 5 } );
```

this will always print the address of the `initializer_list`. When looking at the references, e.g. [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fprintf/), it says

> [...] If format includes format specifiers (subsequences beginning with %), the additional arguments following format **are formatted** and inserted in the resulting string replacing their respective specifiers. [...]

or [microsoft.com](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkh07fe2.aspx)

> [...] Each function argument (if any) **is converted** and output according to the corresponding format specification in format. [...]

So, my question is: How does `fprintf` *format* or *convert* its arguments? Does it use operators? Does it use casts?

Comment: By "converted", Microsoft means "converted into a string according to its format specifier". There is no casting. It's undefined behavior to lie about the type of an argument passed to a variadic function like this.

Comment: Can't you use `operator <<` instead of `printf` ? `std::cout << "I am a hex: " << std::hex << 5;` ?

Comment: `printf` uses `va_list`/`va_start`

Comment: @Jarod42 In this specific instance I could indeed, but I have a code base at hand that uses this kind of print(const char* fmt, ...) a couple thousand times and am not too keen on rewriting every occurrence.

Comment: In C++ you would use variadic templates [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17671772/c11-variadic-printf-performance). In C you use `...` and lose all type information and rely on the format specifier to get it back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fprintf` is a function inherited from C. In particular, it takes a C variadic argument: `int fprintf(FILE*, const char*, ...)`.

You can only pass built-in C types to such a function, not even user-defined C types. Attempting to do so is Undefined Behavior. Trying to pass a `MyType` is dangerous (e.g. the `string` you mention is not allowed). Passing a `std::initializer_list<T>` is *always* Undefined Behavior.

As Jarod states in the comments, use `std::cout <<`. If you need fancier formatting, use `Boost.format`.