# printing out contents of ZZ number

Tags: c++, largenumber, ntl

I am using NTL's ZZ class to work with large numbers. Suppose I have 10000 such numbers, and I want to find the product of all these numbers. Calculating the product of these numbers takes about only 30 secs. However, to print the product of these numbers to the console of the file requires 30 mins! Below is the command I used.

```
cout << product << "\n"
```

Why is this so? Is there any way to speed up the printing of the product of the 10000 numbers? Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried to redirect the output to a file?

Comment: How many digits has your number? The console is really slow, you should try to output in a file.

Comment: @timrau: Yes It is still very slow.

Comment: @Holt: about 3 million digits. I have done that!

Comment: How about the discussions in http://stackoverflow.com/q/1736267/718379 ?

Comment: @freak_warrior, quite congruous. To output 3 million decimal digits, you need to execute 3 million integer divisions. You told us you'd needed 30 seconds to do 10000 multiplications, so 30 minutes for 3 million divisions doesn't seem too much excessive.