# minimize the runtime or the performance time of a code

Tags: performance

I was wondering how i can minimize the runtime of the following code

```
int j = 0;    
while (j < n) {
    int i = 0;    
    while (i < m) {
        cout << i*j;
        i++;
    }
    j++;
}
```

Comment: What is n and m? Is there any constraint like e.g. n < m or so?

Comment: @Dici - *I* know that but...

Comment: Could it be that this is a homework question? What have you tried so far, and what tool do you use to measure the runtime? Also, it would be helpful to know the size of `n`.

Comment: I run it using online compiler it keeps giving me ((Runtime error ))  ... I was wondering why ... it takes O(n*m)  time ... i can use any programming language ,, such as java or c# whatever ,,, the problem is why it takes more than 5sec ... how I can minimize that ..

and no it isn't a homework .. I am still learn how build algorithms with minimum time complexity

Comment: any, m and n ... in general .. if I have two nested for loops or while how I can minimize the time ?

Comment: Depending on the compiler, switching from cout to printf may help performance. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736267/c-cout-printing-slowly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not much to do, these are just mere loops. However, it is usually more efficient to accumulate the strings and print at the end than printing tiny strings several times.

Comment: how I can do that with single loop ... I dnt get it

Comment: You can't, the complexity is `O(n*m)` no matter what.

Comment: I was wondering if i convert it to greedy programing or memoization  maybe these approaches would make it with polynomial time like in greedy it always takes O(m+n) but I dnt know how to convert it to greedy

Comment: I told why it is slow : printing something to the console is much slower than a single iteration in your nested loops, therefore you must accumulate the result and print it in the end

Comment: @majdsoud yes you can, but that's not how I understood your question. This is not only changing the code, this is changing the algorithm

Comment: ok I will try to print it at once and check the time .. thanks

Comment: Tested with `std::ostringstream` as a buffer and there's no significant difference. Use files for such large dump.

Comment: yes .. changing an algorithm to get the best time  ,, cause I already know how it works but trying to make the best time optimization

Comment: I just verified it takes (on my machine) ~1.50x more nano seconds with nested loops vs. a single loop using Java (of course) ;). @majdsoud

Comment: Chief Two Pencils  ... how i can convert it to single loop ?

Comment: @majdsoud, consider what it's doing. `j` is the same for the entire iteration against `m`; dead give-away. Basically the entire outer loop is replaced by an if nested in an if in the loop over `m`- same number of lines of code. Worth it I suppose if you're worried about 0.16 ms.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils man I really don't see what you are talking about. He has `n*m` numbers to print, it is `n*m` computations no matter how you write it. Concerning memoization, it would actually change almost nothing because such a small multplication is not much slower than an addition

Comment: Chief Two Pencils .. it gives me an infinite loop  :(

Comment: @Dici  i think greedy will make it n+m but have no idea how to do that

Comment: @majdsoud what do you mean by greedy ? Really, I tell you, there's no way to significantly boost such a simple computation. The only reasonible optimization is to write to the console **only once** instead of each iteration

Comment: greedy algorithm approach ... you can search about it ...
i will try ti print it once and give u the feedback 
thank you

Comment: I know what is a greedy algorithm, but it has nothing to do with this. A greedy algorithm is an algorithm which tries to optimize a given metric at each step of the algorithm. You are not optimizing a metric here

Comment: All I can say is in my experience simple loops like these average out to be faster if the outer is removed. That may be language or paradigm specific though. What I know is of 100,000 tests ~41% of the time the nested ran faster. But when it did it was even *more* negligible than when the single was faster. In the end the single was 10% faster on average. If it was an algo that ran 24/7/365 the nanos would add up (obviously) and it might be worth it. However, such a micro optimization, if you can call it that since it *may* not run faster for a given iteration, is nit-picking.

Comment: Ultimately though I think saying m*n no matter what is true but neglecting things we have no control over. Taking the complexity of an algorithm is a bound not an exact account.