# Does printf() convert its arguments to string like cout?

Tags: c++, c

I start to learn C++ from C. Recently, I have just read a tutorial book about C++. In section *Introduce to streams*, the book has noted:

> The  << operator is overloaded so that the operand on the right can be
>   a string or any primitive value. If this operand is not a string, the 
>   << operator converts it to string form before sending it to the output
>   stream.

So I wonder whether `printf()` function in C has the same effect. And if it doesn't, please tell me about the differences between both of them.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872543/printf-vs-cout-in-c

Comment: `printf` does that kind of conversion with [format specifiers](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_printf.htm). e.g `int test = 1; printf ("%d", test); `

Comment: Read about [`sprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/), this may be interesting for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, of course it has to somehow generate a string representation of each argument, that is needed in order to have something to print. Printing involves sending streams of characters to an output device after all, you can't print unless you have a sequence of characters.

The `printf()` function uses the formatting string to control how to interpret each argument in order to create the character representation, and also how to format that representation when output.

Note that no "conversion" of the arguments happens that is visible externally, of course. There's no way

```
printf("%d\n", 47);
```

can make that `47` into a string in place; C uses call by value so the function only gets a copy of the value, and it then uses the type information implicit in the `%d` conversion specifier to figure out how to generate the two characters `'4'` and `'7'` that make up the printed representation.

Answer (score 2):

> So I wonder whether printf() function in C has the same effect.

Both C and C++ uses streams for output. In C it is `stdout` and in C++ it is `cout`.

Though it is not evident from  the statement `printf` writes to standard output(stdout) say a terminal.

In case of cout, it is evident from a statement itself, where the output is going.

**Some subtle differences**

With `cout` you might need to include an additional header - say iomanip - and use some functions - say setw() - to have fine formatting where as in `printf` you  rely on format string.

Performance - Each has its own advantage depending on what you print and where you print. I borrowed this point from [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896654/cout-or-printf-which-of-the-two-has-a-faster-execution-speed-c)

**Another similarity**

Both C++ and C standards mention nothing about the order of evaluation of function arguments. So you must not try fancy stuff with functions. For example neither should you do

```
printf(%d%d",++i,i++); // The behaviour is undefined.
```

nor should you do

```
cout<<++i<<++i; // The behaviour is undefined.
```

**Note:**

Remember that the c streams are available in C++ if you include the necessary headers.

Comment: C++ can use `stdout` and the `printf` family for output.  So, one should say that C++ uses streams for output such as `cout` *and* `stdout`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews : That's true, I omitted it for brevity. Just made an edit