# What is the quickest way to print a 2D array of chars?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a simple console game.

I want to refresh console 30 times per second. Usually this is not a problem, but this time I'm working with an array of size 30x30, and printing it using two loops is simply not fast enough.

I noticed that

```
<code>printf( "%s\n", myarray );</code>
```

is quick enough, but it doesn't work properly with 2d arrays.

Is there a function that will make my array appear "instantly" on screen?

I'm using this function to print my array:

```
void draw(char screen[32][31]){
    for (int x=0;x<32;x++){
        for (int y=0;y<31;y++){
            cout<<screen[x][y];
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no quick way unfortunately. You have to write your own.

Comment: Store your 2d array as a 1d array.  Then you can print it with a single traversal. (you would have to embed newlines into it so it prints on multiple lines)

Comment: 30x30 is **tiny** and should be possible to print thousands of times per second. Maybe you're not building with optimisation enabled? Or you're doing something very inefficiently. We can't tell, because you haven't provided nearly enough information in your question.

Comment: 2d array of *what*? `printf( "%s\n", myarray )` implies `char`, but I don't want to assume. If it isn't a `char` array, then what you have is undefined behaviour

Comment: `cout<<endl;` should be `cout<<"\n";`.  `endl` is expensive and should be avoided.  When you are done printing you can call `flush` to make sure the contents are printed.

Comment: since you are using <iostream>, set sync_with_stdio() to false and check. Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/7579656/5281962

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be faster:

```
void draw(char screen[32][31]){
    for (int x = 0; x < 32; x++){
        cout.write(screen[x], 31);
        cout << '\n';
    }
    cout << flush;
}
```

As noted in a comment above, `endl` is the wrong way to insert a newline, because it also flushes the stream and so removes the benefits of buffering done by the I/O library. See [`endl` vs `'\n'`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/213907/981959) for more information.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, it works way faster. Thank you.