# Fast I/O in C++

Tags: c++, performance

I have frequently encountered people writing in their c++ code `ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false); cin.tie(NULL); cout.tie(NULL);`. I do not understand what exactly is the reason of `printf()` and `scanf()` being faster than `cout` and `cin`. I understand that `cout` and `cin` are streams and not functions. However, I am more curious to know what is the underlying mechanism which makes `cout` and `cin` slower than `printf()` and `scanf()`.

Comment: `cin` and `cout` are tied together by default. Performing a read on `cin` first flushes `cout` if it has buffered data waiting to be output. C functions like `printf()` and `scanf()` are not similarly tied together

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896654/cout-or-printf-which-of-the-two-has-a-faster-execution-speed-c) can be helpful.