# Why does printf executes faster than cout in C++?Also scanf is slower than cin,why?

Tags: c++

I've made some programs and saw that scanf and printf are considerably faster than using cin and cout?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cout or printf which of the two has a faster execution speed C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896654/cout-or-printf-which-of-the-two-has-a-faster-execution-speed-c)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, cin/cout waste time synchronizing themselves with the C library’s stdio buffers, so that you can freely intermix calls to scanf/printf with operations on cin/cout.

Turn this off with

`std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);`
Also many C++ tutorials tell you to write `cout << endl` instead of `cout << '\n'`. But `endl` is actually slower because it forces a flush, which is usually unnecessary. (You’d need to flush if you were writing, say, an interactive progress bar, but not when writing a million lines of data.) Write `'\n'` instead of `endl`.

Also as C++ is object-oriented , `cin` and `cout` are objects and hence the overall time is increased due to object binding.

So, a simple one liner, `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);` could make `cin/cout` faster than `printf/scanf`.

Hope this helps you

Comment: In defense of `std::endl`: It can save your ♥♥♥ when your program crashes at the customer and you only have the logs available. The speed loss nowadays almost always isn't that big of a deal so I would take that for the additional safety. Just understand the implications of both approaches.

Comment: Thanks you, now I understand the concept.

Comment: If cin/cout are slower because they are objects, how can it be faster than printf/scanf? Do those flush after every print / newline?