# Under What Circumstances Would sprintf be Preferred to stringstream?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Does anyone have any concrete examples with real reasons as to why one would prefer sprintf over stringstream in a C++ environment? Moreover, if you are working in the Microsoft world is there any reason to ever prefer sprintf to _snprintf?

Comment: Is 'none' a valid answer? And you might want to stick your `sprintf` vs `_snprintf` question under a C tag.

Comment: [Performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/445315/why-is-snprintf-faster-than-ostringstream-or-is-it) possibly but you would have to measure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use `sprintf` all the time in C++.  I find it easier to work with, particularly when I am writing timestamps and other specially-formatted strings.  Sure, you can do this with stream modifiers, but it's so long-winded, you can't see what the code is achieving at a glance.

It is preferable over `_snprintf` if you absolutely know that you won't be overflowing a buffer, and you require the fastest possible write or just don't want the extra parameter clutter.

Speaking of buffers, that's the other thing...  Usually I would use `sprintf` or its variants when I have a buffer on the stack or I am writing into an existing buffer in memory.  I wouldn't necessarily want the overhead of allocating and copying `string` objects about.

Not saying that I don't use `ostringstream` -- I certainly do (although more often I use `istringstream`, going the other way)...  But I prefer to have two tools at my disposal instead of one.

Answer (score 1):

You would never prefer `sprintf` over streams, but you might consider `snprintf` (or `_snprintf` for MS compilers) in some circumstances.

For suitably performance-intensive pieces of code where performance has been measured, `snprintf` might give you a performance boost over using streams.

Additionally you might consider using `snprintf` if you're already maintaining a `char[]` buffer to pass into a C API.

And just to reiterate, you should always prefer `_snprintf` or `snprintf` over `sprintf` because they help prevent a wide variety of security issues and/or hard to find bugs.